# lack of space between signatures on the plot and wrong column order on the plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need create plot using `ggplot2`

Here my code with reproducible example

```
library(tidyverse)
    gemoglabin=structure(list(Therapy.group = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    X.Hemoglobin..g.l...WWScreening = c(139L, 168L, 152L, 122L, 
    142L, 150L, 120L, 157L, 136L, 128L, 157L, 154L, 142L, 124L, 
    138L, 138L, 151L, 148L, 148L, 142L, 149L, 157L, 137L, 135L, 
    121L, 148L, 121L, 159L, 133L, 132L, 155L, 133L, 136L, 121L, 
    140L, 142L, 137L, 147L), X.Hemoglobin..g.L...Visit.1.Day.2 = c(166L, 
    141L, 144L, 121L, 141L, 145L, 121L, 158L, 135L, 121L, 158L, 
    152L, 144L, 128L, 129L, 146L, 142L, 141L, 139L, 139L, 140L, 
    159L, 143L, 132L, 134L, 149L, 123L, 163L, 145L, 141L, 145L, 
    142L, 146L, 121L, 143L, 139L, 145L, 149L), X.Hemoglobin..g.L...Visit.2.Day.9 = c(140L, 
    155L, 142L, 122L, 138L, 143L, 126L, 151L, 129L, 124L, 155L, 
    140L, 140L, 122L, 132L, 136L, 135L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 136L, 
    145L, 138L, 126L, 128L, 144L, 120L, 160L, 143L, 133L, 141L, 
    142L, 147L, 121L, 138L, 139L, 142L, 152L), X.Hemoglobin..g.L...Visit.3.Day.16 = c(150L, 
    157L, 153L, 117L, 140L, 143L, 122L, 155L, 125L, 121L, 156L, 
    144L, 137L, 122L, 136L, 136L, 140L, 140L, 143L, 143L, 140L, 
    143L, 141L, 123L, 129L, 150L, 121L, 163L, 149L, 143L, 136L, 
    136L, 143L, 123L, 147L, 137L, 139L, 152L), X.Hemoglobin..g.L...Visit.4.Day.23 = c(140L, 
    150L, 144L, 122L, 139L, 140L, 124L, 149L, 121L, 125L, 148L, 
    141L, 132L, 126L, 133L, 136L, 137L, 141L, 141L, 137L, 141L, 
    145L, 140L, 120L, 124L, 143L, 122L, 163L, 139L, 132L, 141L, 
    141L, 138L, 121L, 134L, 134L, 137L, 148L), X.Hemoglobin..g.L...Visit.5.Day.29 = c(132L, 
    165L, 141L, 122L, 143L, 140L, 131L, 153L, 123L, 121L, 150L, 
    150L, 139L, 132L, 132L, 139L, 136L, 134L, 145L, 137L, 144L, 
    147L, 134L, 124L, 128L, 148L, 121L, 167L, 142L, 127L, 140L, 
    141L, 144L, 126L, 132L, 134L, 136L, 148L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))


datadim.lng <- gemoglabin %>% pivot_longer(-Therapy.group,names_to="vizit", values_to = "gem")

datadim.lng$Therapy.group <- as.factor(datadim.lng$Therapy.group)

ggplot(datadim.lng, aes(x = vizit, y = gem, fill = Therapy.group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8)+
  theme_classic() +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group = Therapy.group, color = Therapy.group),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.85) 
  )
```

as the result i get such screen
[image]

as we can see here the signatures on the vizit axis are mixed up and i can’t really see which vizit number.

How to make the signatures not mixed and visible? I must have space between visits in plot
[image]

only not in such small print otherwise it is hard to see.

Another problem is wrong order of signatures. `WWscreening` as we can see the first column in dataset ,but in the plot it is last in order

Can you please help me fix  space between signatures and correct order of column in the plot.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two answers here. One is the solution to the question you asked, which is that you can prevent clashes using `guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)`

```r
ggplot(datadim.lng, aes(x = vizit, y = gem, fill = Therapy.group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8)+
  theme_classic() +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group = Therapy.group, color = Therapy.group),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.85) 
  ) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image]

But I think a better answer is that you should rename the levels you are plotting. This will make a plot that is easier for the viewer to parse and understand.

```r
datadim.lng$vizit <- gsub("X\\.Hemoglobin\\.\\.g\\.(l|L)", "Hb (g/l)",
                          datadim.lng$vizit)
datadim.lng$vizit <- gsub("\\.{3}", "\n", datadim.lng$vizit)
datadim.lng$vizit <- gsub("\\.", " ", datadim.lng$vizit)
datadim.lng$vizit <- gsub(" D", ", D", datadim.lng$vizit)
datadim.lng$vizit <- factor(datadim.lng$vizit, 
                            levels(factor(datadim.lng$vizit))[c(6, 1:5)])

ggplot(datadim.lng, aes(x = vizit, y = gem, fill = Therapy.group)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8)+
  theme_classic() +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group = Therapy.group, color = Therapy.group),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.85) 
  ) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, face = 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr::str_wrap` within `scale_x_discrete` to wrap your labels, and `fct_inorder` to convert your column to ordered factor by the order in which they appear.

```
datadim.lng %>% 
    mutate(vizit = fct_inorder(vizit)) %>% # convert to factor in order of appearance
    ggplot(aes(x = vizit, y = gem, fill = Therapy.group)) + 
    geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8)+
    theme_classic() +
    stat_summary(
        fun = median,
        geom = 'line',
        aes(group = Therapy.group, color = Therapy.group),
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.85) 
    ) + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(gsub("\\.+", " ", x), width = 5))
```

the `labels` argument can be provided with either the labels to use or a function that will be applied to all labels. In the above code a function is created that firsts convert the dots to spaces within your column and then uses `str_wrap` for wrapping the words into multiple lines. (`str_wrap` won't work if there are no breaks between words)